# Anime from the 2000s or early 2010s, where they have powers by using gloves with gems in them

Tags: story-identification, anime

The main character is a young girl with a red gem and fire powers and can throw fireballs. One of the side characters got green hacker-like powers. It was dubbed in Albanian and the last arc they showed ended with a destroyed lab.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrickedOutGloves

Comment: @Help pls - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you first watch this? Also, what colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: It was between 2010 and 2015 I think and the mc had brown hair with a hairstyle similar to the mc from a certain scientific railgun

Comment: @Help pls - When you said that one of the side characters got hacker like powers, do you mean like a computer hacker? Also, was that character male or female, and what colour was their hair?

Comment: Well by hacker, she just pulled a green keyboard and did stuff, I dont really remember a lot