# Anime from the mid-2000s to early-2010s, about people with gauntlets which give them powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is all the information I could remember, but since it's been years, it's not much. It was an anime from the mid-2000s to early-2010s, I'm pretty sure (could also be later '90s, but there's a lower probably of that).

In the first episode we see the main character playing baseball, and while playing, she discovers a power in her hand, and a red gauntlet appears, which gives her fire powers and makes her more powerful. In the glove, there is a green gem. Later on, we see other characters with this power.

During the game, a certain organization sees and follows her. She changes schools to one run by her grandfather, where other people with similar powers appear. Of note is a small blond character with a green gauntlet.

The last arc takes place in a laboratory and in the end they are trying to escape it.

Have been looking for this for a good while, but can't find it.

Comment: I just noticed that you posted an unanswered story-ID [question about a very similar-sounding anime](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260298/anime-from-the-2000s-or-early-2010s-where-they-have-powers-by-using-gloves-with) back in February. If you're still asking about the same anime, you really should've edited the previous question to add this extra info to the description, rather than posting a second story-ID question about the same property.

Comment: Alright bet ill got do that, wasn't sure if I should do that or mew post since i dont really use this site much, and was scared just editing might not make people see it

Comment: Editing a question or answer automatically bumps a thread to the top of the list of questions.